# improper integral problem check

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

So we've just started covering improper integrals at school, and the teacher gave us this problem:
$\int_{1}^\infty (xe^{-x})\,dx$. In the solutions, he put down $\frac{2}{e}$, but I got $\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}(-xe^{-x} - \int_{1}^b (e^{-x})\,dx = \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}(-xe^{-x} + e^{-b} - e^{-1}) = -xe^{-x}-\frac{1}{e}$. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: A sign error, and your $-xe^{-x}$ must be evaluated at $b$ and at $1$. If we write $F(x) = -e^{-x}$, the integration by parts yields $$\int_1^b xF'(x)\,dx = \bigl[xF(x)\bigr]_1^b - \int_1^b F(x)\,dx = \frac{1}{e} - \frac{b}{e^b} + \int_1^b e^{-x}\,dx\,.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}&\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}(-xe^{-x} \color{red}{|_{1}^b+} \int_{1}^b (e^{-x})\,dx \\&= 
\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}(-be^{-b}+e^{-1} - e^{-b} + e^{-1}) \\&= \frac{2}{e} \end{align}